# Is there a way to define a new Markdown (MDX) syntax and associate it with an existing tag?

Tags: markdown, gatsby, gatsby-plugin-mdx

Is there a way to define new syntax (`#`, `**`, `-`) for markdown and use it with an existing tag (`strong`, `emphasis`) in Gatsby?

**I want to replace the existing emphasis syntax (`_`) with a double underscore (`__`)**.

I am dealing with Markdown-like syntax implemented in a custom tool, and it uses `__` for italics. I could manually replace the syntax from the MDX file before processing it, but I feel it is a hacky solution.

I am referring to the `MDXProvider` [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-mdx/#mdxprovider) to customize components. I looked through the [remark](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark/blob/main/doc/plugins.md#list-of-plugins) and [rehype](https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype/blob/main/doc/plugins.md) plugins, but I couldn't find anything that I could use to change the syntax.

There may be better ways of accomplishing this in MDX, Gatsby or React. Any pointers/help appreciated.